# how do i give a html div positions dynamic height

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have 3 div displayed as blocks (default), div-one, div-two, div-three, 
i have two inner div in div-one, tab and tabcontent,

```
{box-sizing: border-box}

#div-one {
border: solid 2px red;
display: block;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
   width: 30%;
}

.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  border-left: none; 
}

#div-two {
border: solid 2px blue;
}

#div-three {
border: solid 2px black; 
}
```

currently one height is 0, div-two and div-three height is equal to content height, but div-one content is ontop of them, 
how do i add a height to div-one to fit the dynamic content

```
<div id='div-one'> 
<div class="tab" >
  <button class="tablinks" >London</button> 
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3> 
</div> 
</div>

<div id="div-two" >
<p>Click </p>
</div>

<div id="div-three" > 
  <p>Tokyo </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float: left` declaration on `.tab` and `.tabcontent` removes those elements from the normal flow (but still remains a part of the flow).

- See [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) (MDN)

The "clearfix" hack will contain your floats.

```css
#div-one::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

- See [The Clearfix: Force an Element To Self-Clear its Children](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) (CSS-Tricks)
- See [A new micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) (Nicolas Gallagher)

Also, consider using flexbox. Remove the `float` declarations then add the following declarations (the `width` declarations can also be removed):

```css
#div-one {
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

.tabcontent {
  flex: 0 0 70%;
}
```

- See [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) (MDN)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `#div-one` display property to

```
 #div-one{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
 }
```

it should work.
You can also add the align property to align its content.

```
 #div-one{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
 }
```